# Select from table1 WHERE table2 contains ALL search parameters

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have two tables (notes and tags). Tags has a foreign key to notes. There may be several tag records to a single note record.

I'm trying to select only the notes that contain all of the desired tags.

```
SELECT notes.*, tags.* FROM notes LEFT JOIN tags ON notes.id = tags.note_id 
WHERE {my note contains all three tags I would like to search on}
```

Using WHERE tag.name IN ('fruit','meat','vegetable') will bring back all the notes that have a "fruit", "meat", OR "vegetable" tag. I only want to return notes that have all three "fruit", "meat", AND "vegetable" tags.

I'm ok to bring back multiple records (the query above would yield a record for each tag).

I need help with my where clause. Is it possible to do this without a sub-select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming tags(note_id, tag) is declared UNIQUE or PK, then you can use:

```
SELECT note_id, COUNT(tag) FROM tags
WHERE tag IN ('fruit', 'vegetable', 'meat')
GROUP BY note_id
HAVING COUNT(tag) >= 3
```

Further answer based on OP's comment below.  To get all tags for the records that match:

```
SELECT * FROM tags
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT note_id, COUNT(tag) FROM tags
WHERE tag IN ('fruit', 'vegetable', 'meat')
GROUP BY note_id
HAVING COUNT(tag) >= 3
) search_results
ON search_results.note_id = tags.note_id
```

Comment: But I still need to be able to return all tags associated with the note. This query would return 1 record per note, when there should be as many records per note as there are tags.

Comment: Just join the solution above back to the tags table to get one record per tag.

Comment: I added the SQL to do that JOIN into the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without a subselect, as per request:

```
SELECT  notes.*
FROM    notes
JOIN    tags
ON      tag.note = notes.id
        AND tag.name IN ('fruit','meat','vegetable')
GROUP BY
        notes.id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

More efficient method would be:

```
SELECT  notes.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  to.note
        FROM    tags to
        WHERE   to.name = 'meat'
        AND     EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    tags ti
                WHERE   ti.note = to.note
                        AND to.name IN ('fruit', 'vegetable')
                LIMIT 1, 1
                )
        ) t
JOIN    notes
ON      note.id = t.note
```

The trick here is to put the search on the most selective tag (`'meat'` in my example) on the first place.

Comment: This is close.
I would like to also bring back the tags associated with the note (all tags, not just the ones searched on).

SELECT notes.*, tags.* ...

This really should yield multiple records per note, depending on how many tags there are.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too late, wouldn't it be better to have a NoteTag table - so you will have notes, tags, notetag tables and you can use simple queries and AND operator to find what you want ?)

Comment: For this purpose, notes and tags (with a foreign key to notes) is sufficient, but for the sake of argument, having a separate xref table would still present the same problem.

select all notes (and respective tags) that have match all tags queried by.